# Laravel belongsto

Tags: php, laravel

what i want to do, Checking if "advert_id - auht user id" is in favorite table.

How should the query be?

Advert Table:
| id | name |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1 | lorem ipsun|
| 2 | lorem ipsum dolor|

Favorite Table:
| id | user_id | advert_id|
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1 | 1| 1 |
| 2 | 1| 2 |

Advert Model :

```
class Advert extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        "id",
        "name",
    ];
}
```

Favorite Model :

```
class Favorite extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'advert_id'
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```
$adverts = Adverts::get();
return view("adverts", ["adverts" => $adverts]);
```

View:

```
@foreach ($adverts as $advert)
    @if ($advert->favorite == true)
       checked
    @else
       unchecked
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Fixed :

```
public function favorite(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Favorite::class, 'id', 'advert_id');
}
```

```
$adverts->withCount(['favorite as favorite' => function($q){
    $q->where("user_id", Auth::user()->id);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to know if an advert has an associated favorite model right?
In that case, you should define a relationship in the `Advert` model class that creates a link between a `Favorite` model and the `Advert` model:

```php
// app/Models/Advert.php
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
}
```

Then in your view file:

```php
@foreach ($adverts as $advert)
    @if (count($advert->favorites))
       checked
    @else
       unchecked
    @endif
@endforeach
```

But if you're checking the adverts depending on whether the current user has favorited it then you should also do:

```php
// app/Models/Advert.php
public function isFavoriteOfUser(User $user)
{
    return !! $this->favorites->where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
}
```

Then in your blade file you'd do:

```php
@foreach ($adverts as $advert)
    @if ($advert->isFavoriteOfUser(auth()->user()))
       checked
    @else
       unchecked
    @endif
@endforeach
```